# Mapserver projection conversion

Tags: maps, projection, mapserver, epsg

I have spent dozens of hour trying to find is it possible to change projection with [mapserver](http://mapserver.org/) with no luck so far. My input format is EPSG 3067 and I need to convert it to EPSG 900913 for Google Map use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the MAP object add

PROJECTION "init=epsg:900913" END

this sets the output projection of the map. Then in t LAYER object add

PROJECTION "init=epsg:3067" END

this set the projection that the incoming data for the layer is already in.

You will also need to add the following line to your /usr/share/proj/epsg or the equivalent path if you are on Windows:

## Spherical Mercator projection

<900913> +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +over +nadgrids=@null +no_defs  <>

Comment: I forget to come back here, this is exactly what I found from old blog posts and got it working. This answer is correct!